# [Tensorflow][Object detection] ValueError when try to train with --num_clones=2

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I wanted to train on multiple CPU so i run this command

> C:\Users\solution\Desktop\Tensorflow\research>python
>   object_detection/train.py --logtostderr
>   --pipeline_config_path=C:\Users\solution\Desktop\Tensorflow\myFolder\power_drink.config --train_dir=C:\Users\solution\Desktop\Tensorflow\research\object_detection\train
>   --num_clones=2 --clone_on_cpu=True

and i got the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "object_detection/train.py",
>   line 169, in 
>       tf.app.run()   File "C:\Users\solution\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py",
>   line 124, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(argv))   File "object_detection/train.py", line 165, in main
>       worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)   File "C:\Users\solution\Desktop\Tensorflow\research\object_detection\trainer.py",
>   line 246, in train
>       clones = model_deploy.create_clones(deploy_config, model_fn, [input_queue])   File
>   "C:\Users\solution\Desktop\Tensorflow\research\slim\deployment\model_deploy.py",
>   line 193, in create_clones
>       outputs = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\solution\Desktop\Tensorflow\research\object_detection\trainer.py",
>   line 158, in _create_losses
>       train_config.merge_multiple_label_boxes) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 7, got 0)

If i set num_clones to 1 or omitted it, it works normally.
I also tries setting --ps_tasks=1 which doesn't help

any advice would be appreciated

Comment: python3 issue probably. In `models/research/object_detection/utils/learning_schedules.py` change `range(num_boundaries)` to `list(range(num_boundaries))`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by changing one parameter in my original configuration slightly:

```
...
train_config: {
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "C:/some_path/model.ckpt"
  batch_size: 1
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  num_steps: 25000
  ...
}
...
```

Changing the parameter `replicas_to_aggregate: 1`, or setting `sync_replicas: false` both solves the problem for me, since I was training only on one graphics card and did not have any replicas (as you would have when training on TPU).

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention which type of model you are training - if like me you were using the default model from the TensorFlow Object Detection API example (Faster-RCNN-Inception-V2) then `num_clones` should equal the `batch_size`. I was using a GPU however, but when I went from one clone to two, I saw a similar error and setting `batch_size: 2` in the training config file was the solution.